# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK] android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-2.3-gingerbread

the phone is running 2.3.5 and I set the target and min sdk to 11

this is the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="testchamber.com.listfragmentexample"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="testchamber.com.listfragmentexample.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:theme="@style/AppBaseTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   </application>


  </manifest>
```

this is my build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

android {
compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:11'
buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"

defaultConfig
        {
            applicationId "testchamber.com.listfragmentexample"
            minSdkVersion 11
            targetSdkVersion 11
        }

   buildTypes
        {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
            }
        }


   }

 dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+'
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:18.0.+'
  }
```

I don't see why this shouldn't run on my htc desire hd running 2.3.5 (gingerbread)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API level 11 is Android 3.0. You cannot install an app that declares minSdk 11 to a device running 2.3.5.

To make it install, lower the minSdk to 9 or lower.

Comment: oh , thank you wikipedia told me that api 11 was gingerbread. is there anyway to get fragments on api level 9?

Comment: Yes, support-v4 library provides fragments from API level 4 upwards.

Comment: awesome! you've been a big help thank you very much. I already had support-v4 so I'm ready to go!